# How to keep data "reactive" when creating an array from a Collection

Tags: meteor

I am integrating [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my meteor application. fullCalendar expects a specific [data format](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/). I can create that data from my Collection. However the data is no longer reactive.

What is a way I can make the data I translated from my Collection to an Array "reactive"?

Thanks.

Client html:

```
<template name="carpool_calendar">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</template>
```

Client JS:

```
Template.carpool_calendar.rendered = function () {  
  //initialize the calendar in this template
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
      var events = [];      
      var calendarEvents = Carpool_Events.find();

      calendarEvents.forEach(function (carpool_event) {
    events.push({
          title: carpool_event.owner,
          start: carpool_event.eventDate
    });
    console.log("Event owner " + ": " + carpool_event.owner);
      });
      callback(events);
    },
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    }, 
    weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
    editable: true
  });
};
```

Updated Client JS (This is not quite right yet. Its recreating the calendar on every data change...the page gets longer and longer with new calendar instances):

```
Template.carpool_calendar.rendered = function () {  
  Meteor.autorun(function() {
    //initialize the calendar in this template
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
      events: function(start, end, callback) {
    var events = [];      
    var calendarEvents = Carpool_Events.find();

    calendarEvents.forEach(function (carpool_event) {
      events.push({
            title: carpool_event.owner,
            start: carpool_event.eventDate
      });
      console.log("Event owner " + ": " + carpool_event.owner);
    });
    callback(events);
      },
      header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      }, 
      weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
      editable: true
    });
  })};
```

Client JS Fully working "reactive" fullcalendar:

```
Template.carpool_calendar.rendered = function () {  
  //initialize the calendar in this template
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
      var events = [];      
      var calendarEvents = Carpool_Events.find();

      calendarEvents.forEach(function (carpool_event) {
    events.push({
          title: carpool_event.owner,
          start: carpool_event.eventDate
    });
    console.log("Event owner " + ": " + carpool_event.owner);
      });
      callback(events);
    },
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    }, 
    weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
    editable: true
  });

  Meteor.autorun(function() {
    var calendarEvents = Carpool_Events.find();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  });

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like TimDog said, you can't give the UI element a reactive array, and let it take care of the rest. But another option is you could use `Meteor.autorun` so when your collection changes, it can trigger a JS function to make an updated array, thereby making it somewhat reactive.

I'm not sure how to use this calendar exactly, but adding this into your client side code might help.

```
Meteor.autorun(function() {
    calendarEvents = Carpool_Events.find();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            var events = [];      

            calendarEvents.forEach(function (carpool_event) {
                events.push({
                title: carpool_event.owner,
                start: carpool_event.eventDate
            });
       });
      callback(events);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and report back.

Comment: I tried adding that to my client side code and got the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Carpool_Events is not defined.

Comment: Carpool_Events is supposed to be what you named your Meteor collection variable

Comment: I used the same name as you gave in your code? have you changed it?

Comment: No I haven't changed anything. I will update my post with the updated code so you can see it.

Comment: I have updated my post with a section of code i used that does not cause an error. Seems that if I just put the autorun outside the context of Template.x.y = function() {} then it can't see the variable Carpool_Events. In my updated code it is reactive but its rendering a new instance of the Calendar with each data change. Fullcalendar has something like a refresh data function. I will see how I can use that. Hopefully I will post a full solution this evening. Thanks.

Comment: Updated post with working "reactive Fullcalendar integration with meteor.

Comment: @shinank I've tried your updated post and I'm still getting multiple calendar renders if I add something to the calendar. Did you ever have this issue when adding new items?

Comment: @Chris I do not see multiple "observable" renders of the calendar. How are you checking for the multiple renders and I will do the same and let you know.

Comment: @shinank I solved it by throwing it in a separate template from the parent template it shows on. I used Template.calContainer.rendered = function () {  ... instead of autorun

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a bigger question regarding how to properly create UI components for Meteor that ensure reactive data contexts. It's a very good question and [one that's been asked before](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/hm27ylqgCfo).

The short answer is that there is no standardized framework yet -- like a Meteor.UI smart package. In the interim, however, your best bet is to hack the fullCalendar widget using the {{#each}} helper [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/handlebars/evaluate.js#L33) as your guide. You'll want to pay attention to how data elements are labeled with [Spark](http://meteor.com/blog/2012/08/31/introducing-spark-a-new-live-page-update-engine):

```
 'each': function (data, options) {
    var parentData = this;
    if (data && data.length > 0)
      return _.map(data, function(x, i) {
        // infer a branch key from the data
        var branch = (x._id || (typeof x === 'string' ? x : null) ||
                      Spark.UNIQUE_LABEL);
        return Spark.labelBranch(branch, function() {
          return options.fn(x);
        });
      }).join('');
    else
      return Spark.labelBranch(
        'else',
        function () {
          return options.inverse(parentData);
        });
  },
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't go with this option is because I didn't want to change fullcalendar.

Comment: Glad you got it working...I think you chose wisely for the time being !