# Multi Fullcalendar created when using autosubscribe of Meteor

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I am trying Meteor with fullcalendar to create one booking system. Base on this post([How to keep data "reactive" when creating an array from a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805189/how-to-keep-data-reactive-when-creating-an-array-from-a-collection)), I could make fullcalendar created and refreshed with events collections. But strange things happened while I'm try to add filter for events based on different category, using autosubscribe. There would be multiple calendar tables created in the DIV. It won't occur if all events are returned using subscribe of Meteor.

How it could be resolved? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Snippet of Meteor client JS codes as below:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("Events", Session.get('current_category'));
});

....

Template.doctors.rendered = function() {
    ....
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        var cal_events = [];
        events.find().forEach(function(event_item) {
                var doc_name = doctors.findOne(event_item.doctor).name;
                cal_events.push({
                    title: doc_name,
                    start: event_item.start,
                    end: event_item.end,
                    allDay: false,
                });
            }
        });
        callback(cal_events);
    },
    ....
    });
    ....
}
```

---

#### Solved

The main issue here is 'Template.doctors.rendered' run multi-times, which generates multi full calendar instances.
I moved calendar `<div id='calendar'></div>` as below to a separate template as 'cal_container' and move all codes under 'Template.doctors.rendered' into 'Template.cal_container.rendered'. Now it works.

Comment: Do you want to update calendar on category change or events data change? If the first one is true, just put subscription in the `Deps.autorun()`. Code in autorun will be rerun anytime the Events collection change, so in this function you should pass data to the fullCalendar function.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I resolved it and updated the post accordingly.